# Write Binary tree Struct into file in C

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

Hi I am trying to write the contents of my BST into a file.  So far I have had no luck since it only prints the root and nothing else

My tree structure looks like this

```
typedef struct node
{
char *Emp;
struct node *left;
struct node *right;
}mynode;
```

And my code looks like this

```
void export(mynode *root)
{
File *fp
fp=fopen("Names.txt","w");

if(root!=NULL)
{
export(root->left);
fprintf(fp,root->Emp);
export(root->right);
}
fclose(fp);
}
```

I tried to use printf to only see if it prints it and it does it does.  The problem is that it doesn't write anything after the recursive call even when I put other fprintf statements that say nonsense.

Comment: You keep opening the file and zapping it (`"w"` zeroes the file), writing some nodes to it, and closing the functions current incarnation of it.  You need to do the open and close outside the recursive writing function.

Comment: You are reopening the same file *multiple* times. Once for every recursive call. That is certainly not what you want. All the recursive calls should use the same `fp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is likely that you create a new file every time at the top of your export() function.

What you want to do is to create the file first and pass the handle to your export function. Example:

```c
void export(mynode* root)
{
    File *fp
    fp=fopen("Names.txt","w");
    export_recursive(fp, root);
    fclose(fp);
}

void export_recursive(File* fp, mynode* root)
{
    if(root!=NULL)
    {
        export_recursive(root->left);
        fprintf(fp,root->Emp);
        export_recursive(root->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Nice first answer.  May I suggest that the code fragment currently outside a function should be written in a function, and that maybe the added function should be called `export()` and the fixed recursive function renamed to something such as `export_recursive()` or another name of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Tanguy beat me to it. While his code definitely works, I think it's better to leave the file opening to a different function.

The problem is that you're trying to open an already opened file so `fopen` fails and returns `null`.  Instead, you can do something like this:

```
void export(mynode *root) {
  File *fp;
  fp=fopen("Names.txt","w");

  exportHelper(root, fp);

  fclose(fp);
}

void exportHelper(mynode *root, File *fp) {
  if(root!=NULL) { 
    exportHelper(root->left, fp);
    fprintf(fp,root->Emp);
    exportHelper(root->right, fp);
  }
}
```